# qtwebengine qmake error: unkown module: webchannel

Tags: qt, qtwebkit, qtwebengine

I am trying to get qt webengine running on my laptop for the first time, but can't seem to build it. I am following the instructions from here:

https://wiki.qt.io/QtWebEngineHowToTry

On the last few steps, I had to run "qmake -r" on the qtwebengine directory. This is the output:

```
SSL............................... Using system NSS
ICU............................... Using internal copy (Default, force system ICU with WEBENGINE_CONFIG += use_system_icu)
FFMPEG............................ Using internal copy (Default, force system FFMPEG with WEBENGINE_CONFIG += use_system_ffmpeg)
Proprietary codecs (H264, MP3).... Not enabled         (Default, enable with WEBENGINE_CONFIG += use_proprietary_codecs)
Reading /home/kevin/workspace/qtwebengine/src/src.pro
 Reading /home/kevin/workspace/qtwebengine/src/core/core.pro
  Reading /home/kevin/workspace/qtwebengine/src/core/core_gyp_generator.pro
Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: webchannel
```

This error happened right after I installed WebKitGtk+ from here (http://trac.webkit.org/wiki/BuildingGtk) and ran "Tools/gtk/install-dependencies" and "Tools/Scripts/update-webkitgtk-libs". Before I installed WebKitGtk+, qmake would terminate at a later point.

(I installed WebKitGtk+ because, previously, running "qmake -r" on the qtwebengine directly resulted in an "unmet dependency: harfbuzz" error that I tried to fix on my own via google, and the WebKitGtk+ page was the only lead I could find that would supposedly fix that issue... big mistake!).

I am running on a (mostly freshly reformatted) Ubuntu 15.04 laptop. I installed qt5 via apt-get install, but apparently I have both qt4 and qt5 plugins installed, as well as qtchooser (I'm guessing from the WebKitGtk+ installation scripts).

Here is the output of "qmake --version":

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.4.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I'm excited to try out qt webengine!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has the same problem, I fixed it by installing qt 5.5.0 from here http://download.qt.io/official_releases/qt/, and using the associated qmake binary from that installation. I guess installing qt from 'sudo apt-get install' still has some issues that won't work with qtwebengine.